# Specified DB name with previous year

Tags: sql-server, database

I have some DataBases with name DB2012,DB2013,DB2014,DB2015,DB2016

I have a select statement in a function as below

```
SELECT columnName1,columnName2, ... FROM [DB2015].[dbo].tableName
```

and I have to change this code every year to take previous year but I want to make it generic and take the last year DB name automatically. I couldn't find any solution for that problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current year and previous year and use dynamic SQL to change your query.

```
DECLARE @CURRENTYEAR  AS INT = year(getdate())
DECLARE @PREVIOUSYEAR AS INT = @CURRENTYEAR - 1

DECLARE @QUERY_ VARCHAR(2000)
SET @QUERY_ = 
'SELECT
     COL_1
    ,COL_2
    ...
FROM DB' + @CURRENTYEAR + '.DBO.TABLENAME

UNION ALL

SELECT
     COL_1
    ,COL_2
    ...
FROM DB' + @PREVIOUSYEAR + '2015.DBO.TABLENAME'

EXEC(@QUERY_)
```

Comment: Sorry for delay finally I fixed my problem, thanks for all helps

Answer (score 2):

As people mentioned before me, if you want to do it that way you'll have to use Dynamic SQL.

I want to offer two alternative options that may make your work easier:

The first, is not to seperate databases if it's not really required. It's better adding filtering with date column or something like that. If you combine it with proper partitioning, you'll have great performance and it'll be a lot easier to manage.

If you chose to seperate the databases, it may be easier to create views on a different databses to make querying the data easier  (especially if you want to use an ORM solution from your code, and most of ORM's cant handle that scenario easily).

In that solution, create a new database for queries that use tables/views from multiple other databases. Let's call this new DB "DBReporting".

You can create there standard views that will be like:

```
    select *, 2011 'year'
FROM DB2011.dbo.sales
UNION ALL
select *, 2012 'year'
FROM DB2012.dbo.sales
```

and then querying this view.

You can make it even better: change the view in such way that it will be "Partitioned View", and then SQL Server knows how to work with that to enable deletes and other operations (there's also a support for Distributed Partitioned Views if your data is on multiple servers). You can read about it here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx

This will make querying much easier than working with dynamic sql.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic sql for this:

```
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @year INT

SELECT @year = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1

SET @qry = 'SELECT columnName1,columnName2 ' +
           'FROM [DB' + CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '].[dbo].tableName'

EXEC(@qry)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @year nvarchar(4) = cast(year(getdate()) as nvarchar(4))

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT columnName1,columnName2, ... FROM DB' + year + '.dbo.tableName'

exec(@sql)
```